# How to modify the DbType value for object SqlParameter type

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a variable define like this`object[] parameters = new object[0];`  After run some code it will store some SqlParameter value. [image]

The problem is when i expand the value i wish to change the DbType to AnsiString if the data type is string only. Show in below picture. If the value is int, it will not modify the data type.
[image]

So how to iterate the `parameters` in order to change it? I have try

```
foreach(var item in parameters)
            {
                item.DbType 
            }
```

but is getting error.

Comment: Do not use array of objects. Use [SqlParameters collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1) instead!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best Pactice of Collection of SqlParameters is to create the List and after the execution of command the SqlParameters will have the proper Value of the Sql Query.

So You can create a List of SqlParameters and you can handle it after the execution.

Examples of creating Sql Parameters:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("FromID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = FromID;
cmd.Parameters.Add("ToID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ToID;
cmd.Parameters.Add("User", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = User;
new SqlParameter("Name",[Value]){ SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar, Size = 1000 }
```

Exaple of Insert List of Sql Parameters in SqlCommand

```
private Dictionary<string, SqlParameter> RunSqlStringCommand(string sqlString, List<SqlParameter> sqlParameters)
        {
            try
            {
                using (Database.Connection)
                {
                    Database.Connection.Open();
                    var cmd = Database.Connection.CreateCommand();
                    cmd.CommandText = sqlString;
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    foreach (var item in sqlParameters) cmd.Parameters.Add(item.Value);
                    cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    Database.Connection.Close();
                    return sqlParameters;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

After execution the Sql Parameters if they have the output feature, they have the inserted value from procedure.